# Javascript window.open on IOS 2 window bug

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm getting a little bug using this simple `window.open` javascript function on iOS browsers. When I click it I get 2 windows opening. Has anyone run into this problem and does anyone have a work around?

```
<a href="../html-link.htm" target="popup" onclick="window.open('../html-link.htm','name','width=600,height=400')">Open page in new window</a>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug. You are opening two windows: one because you have an `<a>` with a `target="popup"`, the other one because you `window.open` a `"name"`. The only reason it doesn't happen in desktop is because most desktop browsers would exercise their popup-blocker.